# What is the MS SQL Server capability similar to the MySQL FIELD() function?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

MySQL provides a string function named [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) which accepts a variable number of arguments.  The return value is the location of the first argument in the list of the remaining ones.  In other words:

```
FIELD('d', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
```

would return 4 since 'd' is the fourth argument following the first.

This function provides the capability to sort a query's results based on a very specific ordering.  For my current application there are four statuses that I need to manager:  active, approved, rejected, and submitted.  However, if I simply order by the status column, I feel the usability of the resulting list is lessened since rejected and active status items are more important than submitted and approved ones.

In MySQL I could do this:

```
SELECT <stuff> FROM <table> WHERE <conditions> ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'rejected', 'active','submitted', 'approved')
```

and the results would be ordered such that rejected items were first, followed by active ones, and so on.  Thus, the results were ordered in decreasing levels of importance to the visitor.

I could create a separate table which enumerates this importance level for the statuses and then order the query by that in descending order, but this has come up for me a few times since switching to MS SQL Server so I thought I'd inquire as to whether or not I could avoid the extra table and the somewhat more complex queries using a built-in function similar to MySQL's FIELD().

Thank you,
David Kees

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use a [CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) (SQL Server 2005+):

```
ORDER BY CASE status
           WHEN 'active' THEN 1
           WHEN 'approved' THEN 2
           WHEN 'rejected' THEN 3
           WHEN 'submitted' THEN 4
           ELSE 5
         END
```

You can use this syntax for more complex evaluation (including combinations, or if you need to use LIKE)

```
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN status LIKE 'active' THEN 1
           WHEN status LIKE 'approved' THEN 2
           WHEN status LIKE 'rejected' THEN 3
           WHEN status LIKE 'submitted' THEN 4
           ELSE 5
         END
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a CTE (SQL server 2005+). 
No need to repeat the status codes or create the separate table.

```
WITH cte(status, RN) AS (  -- CTE to create ordered list and define where clause
      SELECT 'active', 1
UNION SELECT 'approved', 2
UNION SELECT 'rejected', 3
UNION SELECT 'submitted', 4
)
SELECT <field1>, <field2>
FROM <table> tbl
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.status = tbl.status  -- do the join
ORDER BY cte.RN  -- use the ordering defined in the cte
```

Good luck,

Jason

Answer (score 2):

For your particular example your could:

```
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(
    ',' + status + ',',
    ',rejected,active,submitted,approved,'
)
```

Note that `FIELD` is supposed to return 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 where as the above will return 0, 1, 10, 17 and 27 so this trick is only useful inside the order by clause.

---

A set based approach would be to outer join with a table-valued-constructor:

```
LEFT JOIN (VALUES
    ('rejected',  1),
    ('active',    2),
    ('submitted', 3),
    ('approved',  4)
) AS lu(status, sort_order)
...
ORDER BY lu.sort_order
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(','+convert(varchar,status)+',' ,   
  ',rejected,active,submitted,approved,')


just put a comma before and after a string in which you are finding the substring index or you can say that second parameter.

and first parameter of charindex is also surrounded by ,
```

Comment: There is an identical answer 2 years older than yours.