# MySQL ordering in Select .. In statement

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I have SQL like

```
select id from user where id IN (2, 3, 1);
```

But MySQL return the row as 1, 2, 3, is it possible to force MySQL to return the order same as my original order 2, 3, 1?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that the order you really want, or are in reality ordering by another column and this is just a simplified example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```
select id from user where id IN (2, 3, 1) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 2, 3, 1);
```

Comment: Nice. Is field widely supported? First I've heard of it.

Comment: MS SQL method, albeit not as pretty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892406/what-is-the-ms-sql-server-capability-similar-to-the-mysql-field-function

Comment: I just found this link on it http://imthi.com/blog/programming/mysql-order-by-field-custom-field-sorting.php

Answer (score 1):

For portable code, use `CASE/WHEN`. It is supported by all (major) dbms.

```
order 
   by case when id = 2 then 1
           when id = 3 then 2
           when id = 1 then 3
       end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also order by LOCATE like this:

```
SELECT
    `id`
FROM
    `user`
WHERE
    `id` IN(2, 3, 1)
ORDER BY
    LOCATE(`id`, "2 3 1")
```

Felix