# order by using terms in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple select query -

```
SELECT ID, NAME 
FROM PERSONS
WHERE NAME IN ('BBB', 'AAA', 'ZZZ')
-- ORDER BY ???
```

I want this result to be ordered by the sequence in which NAMES are provided, that is, 
1st row in result set should be the one with NAME = BBB, 2nd is AAA, 3rd it ZZZ.

Is this possible in SQL server ? I would like to know how to do it if there is a simple and short way of doing it, like maybe 5-6 lines of code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql order by specific ID values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values)

Comment: @showdev: having common "sql" in product names doesn't mean they support exactly the same SQL dialect and functions

Comment: Fair enough. Close vote retracted. Similar concept here, as mentioned in answers below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892406/what-is-the-ms-sql-server-capability-similar-to-the-mysql-field-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an ordered split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings_Ordered]
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT [Index] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number), Item 
    FROM (SELECT Number, Item = SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
      CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
     FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2) AS n(Number)
      WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
      AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
```

Then alter your input slightly (a single comma-separated list instead of three individual strings):

```
SELECT p.ID, p.NAME 
FROM dbo.PERSONS AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.SplitStrings_Ordered('BBB,AAA,ZZZ', ',') AS s
ON p.NAME = s.Item
ORDER BY s.[Index];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the names in a temp table with an order. Example:

```
DECLARE @Names TABLE (
    Name VARCHAR(MAX),
    SortOrder INT
)

INSERT INTO @Names (Name, SortOrder) VALUES ('BBB', 1)
INSERT INTO @Names (Name, SortOrder) VALUES ('AAA', 2)
INSERT INTO @Names (Name, SortOrder) VALUES ('ZZZ', 3)

SELECT P.ID, P.NAME 
FROM PERSONS P
JOIN @Names N ON P.Name = N.Name
ORDER BY N.SortOrder
```

Comment: I am getting the same error - Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.

Comment: Sorry, Order is a keyword (I wasn't intending to use the keyword, just a column name). I updated it to use SortOrder for the column name instead.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get 3 rows inserted and one error -Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid object name 'PERSONS'.

Comment: `Persons` was your table name in your original question. If this is incorrect then update it with your table name (and optionally namespace, e.g. dbo.Persons). Just to clarify, I changed `ID` and `NAME` in the select to `P.ID` to `P.NAME`, in case SQL gets confused about which table to get the name from (though it really doesn't matter since we are joining on name).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this using the order in the `IN` predicate, however, you could create a table of constants giving your constants an order by value:

```
SELECT  p.ID, p.NAME 
FROM    PERSONS p
        INNER JOIN
        (   VALUES
                ('BBB', 1),
                ('AAA', 2),
                ('ZZZ', 3)
        ) t (Name, SortOrder)
            ON p.Name = t.Name
ORDER BY t.SortOrder;
```

The other (and in my option less attractive) solution is to use `CASE`

```
SELECT  ID, NAME 
FROM    PERSONS
WHERE   NAME IN ('BBB', 'AAA', 'ZZZ')
ORDER BY CASE Name
            WHEN 'BBB' THEN 1
            WHEN 'AAA' THEN 2
            WHEN 'ZZZ' THEN 3
        END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, NAME 
FROM PERSONS
WHERE NAME IN ('BBB', 'AAA', 'ZZZ')
ORDER BY CASE 
              WHEN NAME = 'BBB' THEN 1 
              WHEN NAME = 'AAA' THEN 2
              WHEN NAME = 'ZZZ' THEN 3
           END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this must work:

```
ORDER BY CASE 
   WHEN NAME = 'BBB' THEN 0 
   WHEN NAME = 'AAA' THEN 1
   WHEN NAME = 'ZZZ' THEN 2
   ELSE 3 
   END ASC
```