# ORDER BY query throwing error

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-order-by

I'm using a SQL Server database, and selecting records to display contract information. The agreement can either be active, inactive, awaiting response or awaiting payment.

My user wants the grid to display results in this order:

- Awaiting response
- Awaiting payment
- Overdue
- Active
- Inactive

I'm trying to use the following code to achieve this, but it throws an error saying syntax error near the word default.

What is wrong with the order by statement?

```vb
Try
    sql = "SELECT ContractID, CustAcc, DateStart, DateRenew, Fee, Agreement, OtherDetails, " _
        & "DateSent, TimeSent, ReminderName, ReminderEmail FROM dbo.tblContracts " _
        & "ORDER BY FIELD(Agreement, 'AWAITING RESPONSE', 'AWAITING PAYMENT', 'ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE')"
    conAd = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    conset = New DataSet
    conAd.Fill(conset)
    ugModules.DataSource = conset
Catch ex As Exception
    errorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
    MsgBox("Failed to retrieve contract information, refer to error log")
End Try
```

**EDIT**

After changing my code as per the suggestion from @Solarflare, I've now got the following code;

```
sql = "SELECT ContractID, CustAcc, DateStart, DateRenew, Fee, Agreement, OtherDetails, " _
& "DateSent, TimeSent, ReminderName, ReminderEmail FROM dbo.tblContracts " _ 
& "ORDER BY CASE Agreement WHEN 'AWAITING RESPONSE' THEN 1 WHEN 'AWAITING PAYMENT' THEN 2 " _
& "WHEN 'OVERDUE' THEN 3 WHEN 'ACTIVE' THEN 4 WHEN 'INACTIVE' THEN 5 END"
```

However, the result it not as expected. The result is instead as below
[image]

so INACTIVE is mostly at the top, followed by a mix of AWAITING RESPONSE and INACTIVE etc - Why might this be?

Comment: What type of SQL?

Comment: What data type is `Agreement`?  It looks like you are trying to translate it (or something) to that text?  Also. "Default" isnt in the SQL, so its not clear the error is actually from that snippet

Comment: This looks like you are trying to use a mysql function on a mssql server. Have a look at [What is the MS SQL Server capability similar to the MySQL FIELD() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892406/what-is-the-ms-sql-server-capability-similar-to-the-mysql-field-function)

Comment: `ORDER BY FIELD1, Filed2, ..... field_N`

Comment: @Plutonix It's nvarchar(255) datatype in SQL

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks, this is getting me somewhere in the right direction, but see the edit for the final problem this is providing

Answer (score 0):

The ORDER BY should utilize a CASE statement in SQL Server.